# Как устранить ошибку в методе find Vue + Typescript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

Подскажите как устранить эту ошибку

```
 Object is possibly 'undefined'.

55       selected.value = props.options.find((option) => option.id === id).name
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

компонент

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, PropType } from 'vue'

import IconArrow from '@/assets/icons/svg/chevron-down.svg?component'

interface Option {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    IconArrow,
  },
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array as PropType<Option[]>,
      default: () => [],
    },
    default: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: null,
    },
    tabindex: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 0,
    },
  },

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const selected = ref(props.default ? props.default : null)
    const data = ref<Option[]>(props.options)
    const open = ref(false)

    const selectFunction = (id: number) => {
      selected.value = data.value.find((option) => option.id === id).name
      open.value = false
      emit('input', id)
    }

    return {
      selected,
      open,
      selectFunction,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: А ошибка то какая?)

Comment: У вас по дефолту props.options может быть пустым массивом, в таком случае data.value.find((option) => option.id === id) никак вам не сможет вернуть свойство name

Comment: ага) я сделал вот так

const result  = data.value.find(({ id }) => id === id)
      selected.value = result ? result.name: ''

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Оператор опциональной последовательности](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
selected.value = props.options.find((option) => option.id === id)?.name
```

так как метод find по умолчанию возвращает тип T|undefined, так как он не гарантирует, что искомый айтем будет найден.

но учтите, что в таком случае `selected.value` тоже может быть `string|undefined`